# Rep # missing in rep change table on user profile

Tags: bug, profile-page

https://stackoverflow.com/users/3805262/mmlooloo

[image: <td class="rep-amount count-cell"></td>]

Wut?

Ooooooh… It's a 0. Well… why isn't it a 0? Blank ≠ 0. Should be 0.

Comment: Can't see it now. Probably the question with blank rep has been deleted.

Comment: The question wasn't deleted, but the answer was, after a few downvotes due to the meta effect.